# Android conflict google play service version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I implemented new module for an application, using a 3rd party library. In this library, they used `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2`, and in the original application, they used `com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23`. So there was a conflict and I can't sync gradle at all. Is there anyway to fix this conflict ? update google play service of the original project is out of question, because the amount of work would be tremendous.

Comment: plz refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

please reefer this ref: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

and add google play service in your gradle

From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.

Comment: sorry but this couldn't help. The original and the 3rd party both use location and map, from both version of google play service.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Comment: sorry this cannot help.

Comment: you have to replace the lib names with the one you have used. not just copy paste

Comment: I know that ! Let me say this again : the original work and the 3rd party both use location service of google play service, but 1 use version 9, 1 use version 4. Of course I can't exclude the one in 3rd party, and I can't do that for the original project either, because it'll not compile. Unless I have to redo it and upgrade it to the newer version of google play, which is I dont wanna